# VAB of Enterprise Library 6.0 Client Side validation(Jquery/Javascript)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can we perform Client Side validation(Jquery/Javascript) using VAB of Enterprise Library 6.0 with MVC 4.0

Note We dont want to use  Dataanotation .

We have gone thorugh many links but all links showed Dataannotations only for client validation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, so says [this](http://programersnotebook.blogspot.com/2014/03/extending-entlib-vab-part-1-enable.html) link, but i have been unable to get past the problems with multiple validators being adding to the page with the same name.